# hibernate tool,ant,freemarker output encoding

Tags: hibernate, encoding, ant, freemarker

i use hibernate tools with ant.build.xml is below.
it output file encoding is gbk,i want setting encoding utf-8?how? thanks.

```
＜?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?＞
＜project name="hibernate tools" default="generate.code" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"＞
    ＜property name="test" value="target/gen/" /＞
    ＜property name="src.dir" value="${test}src/main/" /＞
    ＜property name="hibernatetools-templates.path" value="src/main/resources/templates" /＞
    ＜artifact:dependencies pathId="toolslib"＞
    ＜pom file="pom.xml" /＞
    ＜/artifact:dependencies＞
    ＜taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="toolslib" /＞
    ＜target name="generate.code"＞
        ＜hibernatetool destdir="${src.dir}" templatepath="${hibernatetools-templates.path}/"＞
            ＜classpath＞
                ＜path location="src/main/resources/" /＞
            ＜/classpath＞
            ＜property propertyFile="src/main/resources/freemarker.properties"/＞     
            ＜jdbcconfiguration configurationfile="src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" revengfile="src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml" detectmanytomany="true" namingstrategy="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" reversestrategy="org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy" /＞
            ＜hbmtemplate templateprefix="pojo/" template="pojo/Pojo.ftl" filepattern="java/{package-name}/{class-name}.java"＞
                ＜property key="jdk5" value="true" /＞
                ＜property key="ejb3" value="true" /＞
            ＜/hbmtemplate＞
        ＜/hibernatetool＞
    ＜/target＞
＜/project＞
```

Comment: it's my fault.we can use ANT_OPTS to set file.encoding.eg.set ANT_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8